# Putting draggables back to their initial position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i would like to create a function that puts my draggables back to their initial position once i call it. Nothing to do with the `revert` function ^^

```
$('.drag').draggable({
        stack: ".drag",
        snap: ".drop",
        snapMode: "inner",
        revert: "invalid",
        start: function(){
            $('.time').fadeIn('slow').delay(1000);
            declenchementChrono()
        }
    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a simple [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) we could play with?

Comment: no i don't :/ but i can explain quickly: it's a puzzle game, so i have to drag and drop pieces to their right position. But once the puzzle is done, i'd like my draggables to go back to their inital position.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to put everything back where it started, is to remove the `style` attribute:

```
$('#reset').click(function(){
    $('#test li').attr('style','');
});

$('#test li').draggable();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lxh58/1/).

Comment: function reset(){
        $(".drag").attr("style", "");
    }    
I tried doing this, but not working :/ and with your exemple, one you reseted, you can't drag them anymore